# Cant get my program to take more than one integer

Tags: java, parsing, int

ok so the goal of my program (very basic at this point) is to take in a string of words for example: ("i give you 34 and you give me 50") and what i want is to populate my array with every occurrence of a number in the string. all this gives me back is the last number i give the code ive checked the whole array and all i can ever get back is the last number.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader read= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String phrase;
    int count = 0;
    int[] numbers = new int[5];
    phrase = read.readLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length()-1; i++){
        if (phrase.substring(i).matches("((-|\\+)?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)+")){
            numbers[count] = Integer.parseInt(phrase.substring(i));
            count++;
            System.out.println(numbers[0]);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your regex just be "[0-9]+"

Comment: Why are you catching floating numbers and using `parseInt`?

Comment: May not be related. `System.out.println(numbers[count]);` before count++ ?

Comment: I think you need to break down your logic line by line. It seems that there are problems in the program logic and that the simple regex will do.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to point out.

- I don't know why you are using a `substring` method on the input.
- You only printed `numbers[0]`. An array isn't good anyway because you never know how many numbers the input will have.
- You are using `parseInt`, when you group on decimal numbers.
- `Pattern` & `Matcher` would be recommended over `String#matches`

---

Here is the corrected code

```
List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([-+]?[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?)");

String phrase = "I give you 30, you give me 50. What about 42.1211?";
Matcher m = p.matcher(phrase);

while (m.find()) {
    numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(m.group()));
}

System.out.println(numbers); // [30.0, 50.0, 42.1211]
```